# How to add SDWebImagePrefetcher in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios5, sdwebimage

Need help urgently.Want to add the SDWebImagePrefetcher methods in swift but it is not accessible don't know why??Other PODS file of SDWebImage are accessible not this one.Any one ???

Answer (score 1):

instead of doing this in Bridging-Header

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
```

do this

```
@import SDWebImage;
```